# MongoDB searching nested array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-aggregation

This is my data.

```
{
    "applianceType": "light",
    "applianceId": "light123",
    "applianceName": "Light",
    "applianceImgURL": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app.tiktok/appliance/icons/lights.svg",
    "inUsed": false,
    "collection": [{
        "category": "ceiling_light",
        "catgName": "Ceiling light",
        "catgImgURL": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app.tiktok/appliance/catg_thumbs/light/ceiling_light.jpg",
        "collectionCatgId": "LI-ceil",
        "items": [{
            "id": "LI-CHL1234",
            "name": "Chandelier",
            "imgURL": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app.tiktok/appliance/thumbs/light/chandelier.jpg",
            "capImgURL": "",
            "inUsed": false,
            "editable": true,
            "quantity": {
                "number": 1,
                "multiple": false
            },
            "value": {
                "state": "OFF",
                "range": {
                    "minVal": "0",
                    "currentVal": "20",
                    "maxVal": "100"
                }
            },
            "rooms": []
        }, {
            "id": "LI-PL1234",
            "name": "Pendant light",
            "imgURL": "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/app.tiktok/appliance/thumbs/light/pendantlight.jpg",
            "capImgURL": "",
            "inUsed": false,
            "editable": true,
            "quantity": {
                "number": 1,
                "multiple": false
            },
            "value": {
                "state": "OFF",
                "range": {
                    "minVal": "0",
                    "currentVal": "20",
                    "maxVal": "100"
                }
            },
            "rooms": []
        }]
    }]
}
```

All I want is to get a particular document of **collection.items**

I have tried this query so far :

```
db.myappliance.find(
    {
        "applianceType": "light"
    },
    {
        "collection" : {
            $elemMatch: {
                "category" : "ceiling_light",
                "items": {
                    $elemMatch: {
                        "id": "LI-CHL1234"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
)
```

This query gives me all the documents inside collection.items array. But I want only one. I know that my question has many duplicate thread already. But I couldn't find any of those answer fit into my case.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to do that on `query`.

After you get the result from the query on the mongodb collections, use that to retrieve the wanted object.

Comment: I just tried your approach. Let me tell you what I did. I am using NodeJS driver.

First I query the outer document i.e. collection object.


`doc.findOne({"applianceType": "light"}, {"collection": {$elemMatch: { "category": "ceiling_light" }}})
    .then(function(docs){})`

This docs object contains the items array. So I did this

`var lightItemData = docs.collection[0];

lightItemData.findOne({ "items.id": "LI-CHL1234" }, {items: {$elemMatch: { id: "LI-CHL1234" }}})
    .then(function(docs2){})

NodeJS is throwing me error that **lightItemData.findOne()** is not a function.

Comment: My answer maybe be a bit misleading. Updated. `docs` is not something that you can use mongodb query on. It's a valid JS object. So, just fetch your wanted field using `for` loop, or filter if you prefer a functional way.